# Biology Question Ovoviviparity in Mammals Mammal/Brid Hybrids

Tags: biology, fantasy-races

I am not sure where to ask this question at so I hope this is a good place.

I also am not sure where I ever got this idea, but I wanted ask what possibility it had.

Considering the reproduction of a species of owl/bear hybrid (an owlbear). Somewhere I got the idea that they offspring would develop in eggs internally and then have a live birth. I believe the process is called, Ovoviviparity, and only know about it being done by amphibians (frogs mainly).

The idea is strange and I liked it for a strange hybrid of a creature, but not sure what all the difficulties of such a process would be.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello Corax Wolves, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and read the following two [help] pages to better understand the limits of our Stack ([help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]). Are you asking, for example, if the egg shells would need to be evaculated and/or reabsorbed into the body? And why did a simple Google look-up for "ovoviviparity" not answer your question (it did for me, in seconds)? It sounds like a perfect real-world reference to create a believable fantasy world.

Comment: @CoraxWolves So, [you've jumped from meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9872/80336) and decided to post on main ^^'. It's not what I would have advised, but ok? Since you're on main, your question is much more subject to closure, so you'll need feedbacks to improve it. [...]

Comment: [...] So here's mine : As it stands, I find a bit unclear what you're asking precisely. For instance what kind of ovovivipar creature hybrid are you making? Fishbears, snaildolphins, Antmonkeys...? Answers might vary and be more focused based upon the "archetype" you choose. The more we know about your issue, the easier it is to answer.

Comment: The creature would be an owlbear.  my question was about regarding the process in general than specifically to using it within the owlbear species, but that is where I am considering using it.  Wasn't sure where to ask this type of a question but specuative biology directed me to worldbuilding.  Didn't realize before I was on a meta and thought the question was closed on that channel.

Comment: You've defined these Owlbears as hybrids, as a hybrid, it would have one parent of each type, presumably an owl and a bear. Hybrids like this are typically sterile, so please clarify what you mean.

Comment: That would be a miss use of the word hybrids.  I am thinking more like the owlbears from D&D but no magical origin.  I read somewhere that someone gave them a dinosaur origin than actually being a fusion of owl and bear.  Not gotten into the issue of evolution or origins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine in small animals like the  [Viviparous Lizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviparous_lizard). The difference between a live birth and developing in an egg inside the body is the former feeds the foetus over time while the latter needs to put all the food inside the egg at the start.

The problem with this for owlbears is a bear takes about nine months to be born while the lizard takes only three months. So the egg needs to be larger. I imagine being warm blooded means it needs to be larger still. The egg might not fit inside the mother!

I suggest instead the young is gestated in a womb with a constant supply of food. Then it is put in an egg and laid and the rest of the growing happens in the egg.

This is slightly more believable and also has more potential for story. Since what is the difference $ \underline{\text{really}} $ between being born from your mother's body, and being born from an egg inside  you mother's body? Not much.

Comment: Regarding what's the difference.  My thinking was that being from an egg meant that one was given everything at start and then no dependent on on the mother afterwards.  This would suggest a more independent solitary creature not tied down.  It's not the best of concepts.

Comment: So even having them lay an egg wouldn't work cause the egg would be too large for the gestation period?  Could the gestation period be shortened?  Is this an issue with the size of the new born?  Is there a link to adult size and size of new born?

Comment: @CoraxWolves I have changed my mind about this. An ostrich chick is warm blooded, weighs a bit over a kilo, and hatches from an egg in 7 weeks. A bear cub weighs a bit less than a kilo. I don't see why it wouldn't in principle fit inside an egg.

Comment: thanks.  Your comments helped me alot.  This was the kind of stuff I wasn't thinking of and needed to have pointed out.  Think I'll drop the ovovivipar aspect and stick with eggs in a nest.

Answer (score 4):

Make the owlbear a marsupial. The egg hatches in the pouch and the young are very undeveloped. They crawl and latch on a nipple for several more months until grown enough to survive on the outside.

Comment: Thought about that.  But a creature with a beak nursing didn't seem like the best of ideas.  thought could do with the beak not forming until later in development to avoid that issue.  

The appeal of using an egg was the independence of not feeding from the mother.  This may not be a good idea either.